# How to show that $x_n$ is convergent?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Given $a>0$, $x_1\gt 0$, $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{a + x_n}$, show that $x_n$ is convergent and find the limit.

That's all the information i have. The problem is i can't bound above the sequence.

Comment: What is the definition of $x_n$?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: In your question, two sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ appear. You define $x_n=\sqrt{a+y_n}$. But there is no definition of $x_n$ (or $y_n$.) You only give a relation between two sequences.

Comment: I think $x_n=y_n$. Is it correct?

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry is x not y

Comment: Is there any more information about $x_1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old question.

There are two cases.

If $x_1\leq x_2.$ Then $x_n\leq x_{n+1}$ and $x_n\leq\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+4a}}{2},$ for every $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ and hence $\lim x_n=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+4a}}{2}.$

If $x_1>x_2.$ Then $x_n>x_{n+1}$ and $x_n>\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+4a}}{2},$ for every $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ and hence $\lim x_n=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+4a}}{2}.$

Therefore 
$$\lim x_n=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+4a}}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The function is increasing, so if $a_2>a_1$ then $a_{n+1}>a_n$ for all $n$.  Likewise if $a_2<a_1$.

Comment: You're telling me to show that (x_n) is monotone, but i already did, i just have to show that it's bounded to say that it is convergent..

Answer (score 0):

#### Hints:

1. Start by figuring out what the limit must be if there is one. Note in particular that there is only one possibility.
2. To prove convergence, add in Michael's approach (i.e., recognizing that the sequence is monotone). In particular, consider what happens if $x_1$ is very large and what happens if it is very small.

Comment: It must satisfie a quadratic equation, but the final expression for the limit is too large...maybe i can use it anyway but how?